VMware ubuntu stuck on boot after expanded disk
VMware Ubuntu stuck on boot after expanded disk. How can I solve this?


Please describe exactly what/how you did ...

Have you tried to boot on a Live/install image, verify and mount the virtual disk ?

@SorenA First I increased disk size in VMWare then in ubuntu I resize disk with using free allocated disk. Then I reboot but it stuck on starting.

Then boot from install-media/image and check the (virtual) disk you just expanded. Also check log-files in /var/log (on the virtual  disk) if there are any messages about problems when booting.
